# Select sum with joining table on gorm golang

Tags: go-gorm

Let assume i have 3 model like this

```
type Violation struct{
  ID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  ViolationName string
  ViolationPoint int
}

type Student struct{
  ID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  StudentName string
}

type ViolationRecord struct{
  ID uint `gorm:"primaryKey"`
  ViolationID int
  V Violation `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;foreignKey:ViolationID;references:ID"`
  StudentID int
  S Student `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;foreignKey:StudentID;references:ID"`
  RecordDate time.Time
}
```

Everything gonna be fine for CRUD system, but the new request is show total of the violation record/ student and sum the violation point.

i have try this

```
type ViolationSummary struct {
    count int
    sum   int
}

func(s *Server) ShowSummary(id int){
  var vs ViolationSummary
  s.DB.Table("violation_records").
            Select("count(violation_records.id) as count, sum(violations.violation_point) as sum").
            Joins("left join violations on violation_records.violation_id=violations.id").Where("student_id = ?",id).Scan(&vs)
  fmt.Println(vs.count)
  fmt.Println(vs.sum)
}
```

but this function always show 0 value

Answer (score 0):

I Have solve my problem with this code, i hope it can help.

```
func(s *Server) ShowSummary(id int){
 vr:= []models.ViolationRecord{}
 var total int64 = 0
 var point int64 = 0
 err:= s.DB.Where("student_id = ?",id).Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&vr).Error
 if err != nil {
 fmt.println("Error on load data")
 }
 for _, element := range vr {
        total += 1
        point += int64(element.V.ViolationPoint)

    }
fmt.println(total)
fmt.println(point)
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.